# Malwares source repositories. Where?

Tags: malware, source-code, research

As the best way to learn is to read the code, do you know where I can find malware/virus/whatever source code to read?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Update:  I added the link below after a reading a twitter message
**"Links and resources for malware samples"**
http://contagiodump.blogspot.com/2010/11/links-and-resources-for-malware-samples.html

Malware specific:

> If you have money:  http://www.frame4.net/home
>   Free (and paid):  http://www.offensivecomputing.net/

Exploits:

> http://www.exploit-db.com/
>   "The Exploit Database (EDB) – an ultimate archive of exploits and vulnerable software. A great resource for penetration testers, vulnerability researchers, and security addicts alike. Our aim is to collect exploits from submittals and mailing lists and concentrate them in one, easy to navigate database."
>   http://www.packetstormsecurity.org/ is another one

Comment: These are exploit, advisory and vulnerable apps repositories, there are no malware samples as I know.

Comment: I may have taken the ‘whatever source’ from the question too liberally – I added a couple malware specific resources, thanks!

Comment: exploit-db.com does not offer any malware source code. It only list vulnerabilities of known 'innocent' and widely used softwares.

Answer (score 4):

Here are different samples of malware: http://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showforum=51. Also, you can setup honeypot (like this: http://code.mwcollect.org/projects/show/mwcollectd) to collect samples on your own.

Answer (score 3):

If you're willing to contribute back, set your machine with Dionaea honeypot and enable XMPP support. You could leech malware from your friends out there.

Also, if you extend a bit your Dionaea config and apply for "freelance" account with http://alliance.mwcollect.org you could get access to their bulky malware repositories and automatically download Windows malwares as you wish.

Milla's (contagiodump) blog is pretty good too. Recently she did update her blog with Mobile malware.

Answer (score 2):

The [SecurityFocus](http://www.securityfocus.com) website often has exploit code for vulnerabilities reported there.

Comment: SecurityFocus has been known to manipulate exploits so they no-longer compile and/or run.