# Resource of malware source code written in C/C++

Tags: malware

I've started to study malware analysis and have dissected a few binaries.

However, I'd like to view the source code of some malware (C/C++) in order to get better insight.

I am mainly interested in backdoors and worms, but I would also be interested in other topics like malware for the web.

Could someone point me to a good resource - especially one that does not assume you have already created lots of malware yourself.

Comment: unfortunately, whatever list we give you today might be dead tomorrow - so questions like this are off-topic. There have been other questions in the past that have been asked and answered that might suit your needs. Like http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/277/malwares-source-repositories-where?rq=1

Comment: The google search term "c++ malware source code" returns rich results